# I don't see why this question is on hold because of "too broad"

Tags: discussion, moderation, reopen-closed

[How to achieve read/write separation with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773560/how-to-achieve-read-write-separation-with-entity-framework)

The question is very specific (though, granted, consists of a few "sub-questions"):

- How would I implement this (99% of the topics on SO are about the (correct) way to implement something)
- Is it even supported at all ("out of the box"), and if so (see former) what would I need to do to implement it.

I've put a lot of effort in my explaining the problem and conclude with a relative concise question (for the problem at hand). Lately I've had more questions closed (such as [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119868/rest-web-api-claims-identity-refresh-per-request) which I had to move to codereview because "too broad" and even put a (now expired) bounty on it but it only had 98 views because that site is WAY less popular) and quite honestly it's becoming more and more frustrating here on SO.

There's gazillions of easy to ask (and easy to answer) questions but as soon as the question needs a bit of an introduction/explanation or is a bit more complicated than "*why doesn't my `print("hello world)` not work??*") it's "too broad", is closed because of "unclear what you're asking" or should be posted elsewhere in the stackexchange network where it's just as "offtopic" but you're forced to go there because it's not allowed *here* and with the consequence of getting no, or very low, exposure.

As a more experienced programmer I kind of start feeling less and less welcome at SO where, to me, it seems only (mostly) simple questions with only (mostly) simple answers are welcomed. Sure there are tons of more complicated questions to be found (so don't go looking for examples to "prove me wrong") but the bulk of it makes for a different picture.

Comment: The only specification you have is that it must use work with the entity framework, you haven't settled on a specific technique for solving this problem, so anyone's open to solve it in any way they want. of course, that's the kind of answers you're probably looking for, but some may argue that makes it too broad. I don't think it is, but I'm also not familiar with the technology stack you're using.

Comment: Voted to re-open. Any implementation of the desired pattern is going to be tightly bound by the capabilities of the desired framework. Perhaps refine the question by stipulating what patterns you are trying to avoid (further abstractions of your DAL, for example).

Comment: @KevinB: `you haven't settled on a specific technique for solving this problem` Correct; because I don't know of any; that's exactly what I'm asking for: a technique to solve this problem. `but I'm also not familiar with the technology stack you're using`; I understand but the technology stack (.Net, EF) is the "limiting factor" here so I don't think it's broad at all because there are likely only a few (if any at all) ways to solve the problem, as Gusdor (correctly IMO) notes: `Any implementation of the desired pattern is going to be tightly bound by the capabilities of the desired framework`

Comment: Right, but what I'm saying is some people will still see that as too broad. I'm not saying they are correct or wrong in that observation. Voting to close is of course a subjective decision, which is why it usually requires a consensus.

Comment: @KevinB `I'm not saying they are correct or wrong in that observation` I got that, sorry if that wasn't clear. And I *can* also see it in *some* cases; I just don't agree in *this particular* case; which is why I created this meta-question ;-) Your feedback is appreciated nonetheless!

Comment: This looks alot better and clearer then most of the tosh Im seeing here on a regular basis. Voted to reopen.

Comment: ".. it usually requires a consensus" and in this case a moderator used his **Moderator** Privileges to immediately close the question. If a `C#` Gold badge owner did so (or, if such a thing exists, a gold badge owner for `sql-server` or `replication`) one could argue 'well he must know what he's talking about'. The single close voter does not have such badges and so used his moderator privileges instead. In this case it's not clear why it was closed.

Comment: Votes for reopening are welcome ;-) I also wonder why this meta-question is getting downvoted (nobody caring to leave a comment when downvoted). SO and related sites are going downhill quickly IMHO... sad.

Comment: @RobIII how can you be so sure the downvoters haven't commented?

Comment: @KevinB Aw, c'mon man, now we're going for semantics.... I'm not *sure* ofcourse, but I would've expected at least a decent explanation for a downvote and I see none of that in any of the comments. But sure, it *could* be any of the commenters. You're absolutely correct. Fine.